# Need help decoding a warning

Tags: r

Data frame 'vpsots' has a variable 'type', with 13 levels (given below), while exploring the dataframe for the heck of it tried to remane SUV with suv (just to see if I can).  What should I make of the warning in the code below.  I see that SUV was changed to NA's.  I presume it has something to do with the variable 'type' being a a factor.  Is it because level 'suv' does not exist.  I am trying to get better at reading warning signs and would like suggestions.

```
> unique(vposts$type)
 [1] coupe       SUV         sedan       hatchback   wagon       van         <NA>       
 [8] convertible pickup      truck       mini-van    other       bus         offroad    
13 Levels: bus convertible coupe hatchback mini-van offroad other pickup sedan SUV ... wagon
> vposts$type[vposts$type=="SUV"]="suv"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, vposts$type == "SUV", value = c(3L, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> unique(vposts$type)
 [1] coupe       <NA>        sedan       hatchback   wagon       van         convertible
 [8] pickup      truck       mini-van    other       bus         offroad    
13 Levels: bus convertible coupe hatchback mini-van offroad other pickup sedan SUV ... wagon
```

Comment: The column is `factor`.  Convert to `character` and the warnings will be gone.  The reason is that the factor doesn't have that level `suv`.  You should either have that `level` added before replacing or convert to character.

Comment: The factors are case-specific. "suv" is not one of the factors so it will be coerced to `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to rename the levels of a factor, you can do the following using `levels` function:

```
# Create a factor with each alphabet letter as levels.
a_factor <- factor(substring("statistics", 1:10, 1:10), levels = letters)
summary(a_factor)

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z  
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0

# Rename the level whose name is "c".
levels(a_factor)[levels(a_factor) == "c"] <- "CE"
summary(a_factor)

a  b CE  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  
1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
```